# How to mark view do not need layout_width and layout_height in Android XML layout

Tags: android, android-xml

Define some custom views with default layout_width and layout_height by override `SetLayoutParams` and Constructor method.  But Android Studio reports View need layout_width and layout_height.

TableRow do not need layout_width and layout_height as docs says.

Answer (score 0):

When an Activity receives focus, it will be requested to draw its layout. The Android framework will handle the procedure for drawing.

> When a View object's measure() method returns, its **getMeasuredWidth()** and **getMeasuredHeight()** values must be set, along with those for all of that View object's descendants.

So initially you have to set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of a view and afterwards you can change it dimension and visibility according to your requirements.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws).